# Elements with "nowrap" in table row prevents entire row from wrapping in IE8

Tags: html, css

I am forced to do some development that will be compatible with IE8.

Starting with this code, we see that as the window shrinks the table wraps the text in a way that separates it from its radio button:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html><body>
<table style="border-collapse:collapse; border:1px solid black"><tr>    

<td style="border-collapse:collapse; border:1px solid black">
    Foo
</td>

<td style="border-collapse:collapse; border:1px solid black">
    <label style="white-space:normal"><input type="radio" />
        Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar
    </label>
    <label style="white-space:normal"><input type="radio" />
        Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar
    </label>
    <label style="white-space:normal"><input type="radio" />
        Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar
    </label>
</td>

</tr></table>
</body></html>
```

[image: dfd]

So, changing the `white-space` style of the 3rd element to `nowrap` seems to fix the problem.  It will now force the radio button and all of the text to wrap together.

```
<td style="border-collapse:collapse; border:1px solid black">
    <label style="white-space:normal"><input type="radio" />
        Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar
    </label>
    <label style="white-space:normal"><input type="radio" />
        Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar
    </label>
    <label style="white-space:nowrap"><input type="radio" />
        Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar
    </label>
</td>
```

[image: fd]

However, if you shrink the window further, the problem persists with other elements, so lets also change the first two elements to `nowrap`:

```
<td style="border-collapse:collapse; border:1px solid black">
    <label style="white-space:nowrap"><input type="radio" />
        Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar
    </label>
    <label style="white-space:nowrap"><input type="radio" />
        Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar
    </label>
    <label style="white-space:nowrap"><input type="radio" />
        Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar
    </label>
</td>
```

[image]

Now the entire table cell no longer wraps!

It works properly in Firefox, but not in IE8.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: off topic, probably, but why are you misusing the `label`? place the `input` outside of it and assign it with a `for` attribute to associate it with the `input`.

Comment: PS - tables for layout are so 1761. lose them and you lose those issues.

Comment: add `white-space:normal`

Comment: @EliranMalka I am using labels this way as suggested in a post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512695/how-do-i-prevent-line-breaks-between-a-radio-button-and-its-label-while-still-a

Comment: @EliranMalka Try it that way you say, and you will see that radio button and text will not even wrap together.  You can have a situation where the radio button is on one row and the text has wrapped and carriage returned below it. This is even worse!

Comment: @hawaii.five-0 Add... where?  I already have that attribute in many parts of my code.  Very confused what you are trying to say.

Comment: **a.** nice, wasn't familiar with that (containing inputs inside labels), **b.** you should use CSS for layout rather than tricking your browser to perform flow tweaks to the document.

Comment: @EliranMalka But this *is* CSS.  To make it simple here I used inline CSS instead of a separate sheet, but the principle is the same.  I would say that semantically CSS is roughly the same thing as "tricking a browser to perform flow tweaks." ;-)

Comment: ok ok i hear you.. was just being picky.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `float` to solve that issue:

```
<td style="border-collapse:collapse; border:1px solid black;">
  <label style="float:left;"><input type="radio" />
    Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar
  </label>
  <label style="float:left;"><input type="radio" />
    Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar
  </label>
  <label style="float:left;"><input type="radio" />
    Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar
  </label>
</td>
```

See this [working example](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/76169930/stackoverflow/question/10889601/index.html)!

This way the wrap does not occur and if the window gets extremely small, the wrap still proves useful.

Comment: Thanks, it works.  I would have never thought to use float for something like this!  Although I have a small modification... if I use the exact code as you have above, it still allows the table cell to get so small that part of the "bar bar bar" can get wrapped below the radio button.  However if I used your float style AND my original `nowrap` style together, then it has 100% the effect I want.  Unfortunately I cannot view your link right now (firewall) but will check it out later.  Thanks again!

Comment: @The111, yap, I've left it to get wrapped, because if you have issues with a small window, the _Bar Bar Bar_ should in fact break to preserve the layout width! But adapt it to fit your needs! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `white-space: nowrap`, set

```
label { display: inline-block; }
```

[Support to `display: inline-block`](http://caniuse.com/#cats=CSS) is rather universal nowadays (in a case like this, where the element has `display: inline` by default).

P.S. The bug with `white-space: nowrap` described in the question still exists in IE 9.

P.S. 2. For usability and accessibility reasons, multiple radio buttons on one line should be avoided. Applying this principle, the situation does not arise.

Comment: Thanks, that does work too and I believe it is cleaner since it doesn't require an extra style to "fix" the bug with recognizing `nowrap` (and thank you for verifying that is an actual bug and not just a "difference between IE and FF").  Regarding the in-line radios... that layout is being dictated to me, and while I mostly agree with your logic, in this case it actually does make sense, somewhat, if you could see the layout you might agree.

Answer (score -1):

Try this - because there is already a trailing whitespace (newline is treated as space) at the end of the label, all others are ignored (collapsed into it), BUT that one is not wrappable (so just axe it):

```
<td style="border-collapse:collapse; border:1px solid black">
    <label style="white-space:nowrap"><input type="radio" />
        Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar</label>
    <label style="white-space:nowrap"><input type="radio" />
        Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar</label>
    <label style="white-space:nowrap"><input type="radio" />
        Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar</label>
</td>
```

Comment: Nope, does not work.  I did not downvote you by the way... nor will I upvote you though. ;-)

Comment: meh, worth the try at least, the logic was sound... and haters gonna hate ;-p

Comment: Haha yeah, I actually had a similar idea myself, inserting a single wrappable element before all the nowraps, but it didn't work, and would have felt cheap even if it did!  Thanks anyway.