# How to prevent HTML automatic line breaking between field and button

Tags: javascript, css, html, freemarker

[image]

Hi,

I'm currently in the process of making a web app that consists of the above field and button the code is below. Although I removed the actual button code to protect my works privacy. Does anyone know by any chance how to make it so both these objects are on the same line.

Thanks

Brad

```
<td class="two td_left" nowrap="nowrap">${row.ACCO60?html} (Code for button here followed by the closing td tag)
```

@stett Here is the generated HTML code at runtime for that specific part of the table.

```
<

td class="one td_left" nowrap="nowrap">Ref</td>
                        <td class="two td_left" nowrap="nowrap">10004 
<a height="" href="javascript:void(window.open(Don't need to see this part))" id="squarebutton" linkedtype="M" mrc="" width=""><span>Amend company details</span></a>
</td>
```

Comment: Please provide more info.

Comment: Well I have removed the &nbsp; from between the ${row.ACCO60?html} and the button code thinking it was that but it wasn't. I've googled it and apparently using nowrap works and so its supposed to bring the button up onto the same line as the 10004 but I've had no luck.. :/ What other info are you after?

Comment: Can you provide `html` rendered by your browser??

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/512695/631619

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola I have just added that edit for you

Comment: @MichaelDurrant Best answer so far. Just in case I haven't made it clear I haven't got access to the external css therefore this answer is perfect to attempt to do some internal styling thanks Michael much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Without the actual html that is generated by the expressions `${row.ACCO60?html}` and the button code, it's hard to directly advise on the styling necessary to achieve what you're going for, but my instinct is (in the CSS) to select for those elements, and set their display mode to inline or inline-block using the following CSS statement:

```
display: inline-block;
```

[This](http://learnlayout.com/inline-block.html) tutorial provides a fuller explanation of inline-block elements.

Comment: Unfortunately they are all linked to the same crm css file so I have no flexibility when it comes to that file.

Answer (score 0):

Put your ${row.ACCO60?html} in a div, and set the styling for the containing div and the button to:

```
#divId {
    display: inline;
    width: x%;
}

#buttonId {
    display: inline;
    width: y%;
}
```

, where x + y <= 100. This will tell the browser to display the second element on the same line, if possible, and set their combined width to a size less than or equal to the size of their containing element (the td).